# Multi line comments in SBT

Tags: sbt

Is it possible to comment out an entire block of text in SBT, similar to `/* Java style block comment */` syntax? I'm getting some build errors and can only use multiple single line comments instead.

The build error I see is 
*Error parsing expression.  Ensure that there are no blank lines within a setting* as well as an *illegal start of simple expression*
with the line number indicating the closing */

Answer (score 2):

Try `/*** comment */`

Note: settings are allowed in there too.

Comment: Tried this but still getting the same error messages